# Hello...I have a small problem with the JQuery Date Picker Range

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, range, picker

I have two date pickers..The first is the "From or Starting Date" and the second is the " TO or Ending Date". What i need to do is to be able to add one year to the Starting date and then automatically display that value in the Ending Date. I am quite new to Jquery and need help with it. Thanks a million in advance..

Comment: Which date picker are you using and please provide your current code as an example to work with. In general, providing a code sample goes a long way in convincing people that they should spend time helping out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#FROMpicker').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
     $('#TOpicker').datepicker("setDate", $(this).datepicker("getDate"))
                   .datepicker("setDate", "+1y");
   }
});
```

At the bottom of [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker) see the "Events" and "Methods" tabs for explanations.